# How are prompt boxes displayed in Windows?

Tags: windows

I am curious as to how prompt boxes are displayed in Windows.

Furthermore, I would like to know how and where this is routed from in the instance of the Recycling Bin's delete confirmation.

I don't believe that Windows uses JScript, though I wouldn't know as a matter of fact.

Is this a .NET framework function/task ?
ASP.net ..seems to generate some result, but, I don't have much grounding reference lol as to what that is

That should not detract from the question in any way, as I also want to know which file/protocol/DLL (perhaps, actually..has ANY) relation to Recycling Bin and its proper functioning.

Thank you

Comment: I believe most of Windows is written in C. The desktop, start menu, and more, is managed by the explorer.exe process with much of the functionality in shell32.dll. There are many support DLLs. The inner working of the recycle bin is largely undocumented

Answer (score -1):

The confirmation dialog box is a .NET function for applications.  Some Windows "apps" used to be [HTML applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) in older versions of Windows, I do not think Windows 10 still uses HTML applications any more.  HTML applications would have a script based confirmation dialog box.

As for the Recylce Bin, I would definitely think that is a .NET application.  However, I have not looked into it.